# Why I cannot delete a cookie?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I have following code in my `Home`-controller:

```
public ActionResult MyPage()
{
    if (HttpContext.Request.Cookies["User"] == null)
    {
        //Create cookie
        return RedirectToAction("MyPage", "Home");
    }
    else
    {
        string User = HttpContext.Request.Cookies["User"].Value;
        foreach (var user in Data.MyUsers)
        {
            if (user.username == User)
            {
                //Do some stuff
                return View("MyPage");
            }
        }
        HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Remove("User");
        //HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Remove("User"); works not sorry ;(
        return RedirectToAction("MyPage", "Home");
    }
}
```

**Problem**: The application don’t delete the cookie (why ever) and run in a loop because the application doesn’t find the user in the data. (The problem is not that the application doesn’t find the user, the problem is the cookie-issue)

**Question**: How I can fix this issue because in another project of me I works fine. I copy and pasted the code from my other project in my new project, but in the new project it will not work. Yes I use the same version of the asp.net framework :)

Hope you can help me… I’m at the end of my knowhow about c#....

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Expire Property, and set negative value to it, this will expires the cookie i.e in your word this will removed from cookies list.

```
String cookieName = Request.Cookies["User"].Name;
HttpCookie userCookie = new HttpCookie(cookieName);
userCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
Response.Cookies.Add(userCookie);
```

Comment: This works but it feels that is not the right way to do this…

Comment: As per my experience and knowledge this is the only way i know

Answer (score -1):

You cant delete a cookie on client, but you can do expire

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178195.aspx